# Safety of map operator[] when you dont want a default constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, default-constructor

I recently ran into an interesting bug with a program at work. I would like to know a little bit more about how `operator[]` works with maps. Consider the following example code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

class test
{
    public:
    test(int a, char b) {
        a_ = a;
        b_ = b;
    }

    void print() {
       std::cout << a_ << " " << b_ << std::endl;
    }

    private:
       int a_;
       char b_;
 };  


int main()
{
    std::map<int, test> mapper;
    mapper.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple<int>(1),
            std::forward_as_tuple<int, char, double>(1, 'c', 2.34));
    mapper[1].print();
}
```

The code is very simple, and the objective is pretty clear, I dont want to have a default constructor for the class test. This code wont compile however, because `mapper[1].print()` calls the default constructor.

The obvious solution here is to replace `mapper[1].print()` with `mapper.find(1)->second.print()`. I am just interested in why it is necessary for mapper[1] to create a `test`. Does this mean that every time in any code i have written with a map using `operator[]` that it creates a default and copies the class before calling its functions?

This seems like a huge waste of time, i understand its necessity during something like this: `mapper[2] = test(1, 'a')`. Is there not any way that it could tell that its not part of an `operator=` call? I guess not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from Visual Studio 2012 library

```
mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& _Keyval)
    {   // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped
    iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);
    if (_Where == this->end()
        || this->_Getcomp()(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
        _Where = this->insert(_Where,
            pair<key_type, mapped_type>(
                _STD move(_Keyval),
                mapped_type()));  // <---- call to default constructor
    return (_Where->second);
    }
```

as you can see it require `mapped_type` to be default construable to compile doesn't means it need to construct the object every time you call `operator[]`

Comment: Right, that makes sense, is this the implementation of the stl map?

Comment: Nice. That makes sense and is re-assuring.